# Scilab 'load' command results in boolean

Tags: scilab

using 'load' for the sample below results in Boolean output instead of the stored data

```
> --> a=rand(3,3)  
>  a  = 
>    0.8833888   0.9329616   0.3616361
>    0.6525135   0.2146008   0.2922267
>    0.3076091   0.312642    0.5664249
> 
> 
> --> save ('rand_matrix.dat','a')
> 
> --> ls  ans  =
> 
>  rand_matrix.dat
> 
> 
> --> load("rand_matrix.dat",'a')  
> ans  =
>   T
```

Comment: have you read the original page for load function  https://help.scilab.org/doc/5.5.2/en_US/load.html

Answer (score 0):

first of all it would be great if you could spend some time learning MarkDown to be able to have readable posts here on StackOverflow. Your original code block was distorted. Please take a look at how I have edited it so next time you can use the same format. Secondly try to look into the original page of the functions you are trying to use, in advance to posting a question. In this case [the page](https://help.scilab.org/doc/5.5.2/en_US/load.html) have implicitly explained that this is the expected behavior.  Lrt's go through your codes:

```
--> a=rand(3,3)
 a  = 
   0.2113249   0.3303271   0.8497452
   0.7560439   0.6653811   0.685731 
   0.0002211   0.6283918   0.8782165

--> save ('rand_matrix.dat','a')
```

This will create `rand_matrix.dat` on your current working directory and stores the value of the variable `a` there in binary format. Now if you remove `a` from your workspace:

```
--> clear a
--> a
Undefined variable:a
```

and use the load the variable and its data again from the file

```
--> load("rand_matrix.dat",'a') 
 ans  =
  T

--> a
 a  = 
   0.2113249   0.3303271   0.8497452
   0.7560439   0.6653811   0.685731 
   0.0002211   0.6283918   0.8782165
```

It will be loaded to the workspace again. The `T` the `load` function returns means that it has successfully loaded the file and the variable.